# Made changes to Vagrantfile - now my vagrant will not start

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I made some changes to my Vagrantfile. All I did was to add more processors and ram to the config.

Before (and commented out):

```
....

#config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #  vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  #   vb.cpus = "2"
#end

....
```

After:

```
....

config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
    vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
     vb.memory = "1024"
     vb.cpus = "2"
end

....
```

I rebooted the machine and got this error:

The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

`If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run`vagrant up`while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.`

`The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.`

So I changed my Vagrantfile back to how it was originally (as above).

I still can't boot the machine with `vagrant up`. What have I done wrong?

When I do have the UI enabled. It just opens and closes without me being able to see it.

Comment: What do you get for `vagrant status` ?

Comment: whats happening if you just start the VM from VirtualBox directly without vagrant ?